# Running multiple slideshow loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, slideshow

I have four slideshows on one page that I want to just run in loops.  They're quite simple, based on [Jon Raasch's](http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow) simple JQuery slideshow.

I'm great with mark-up and CSS, but not yet very proficient with javascript.  Right now, I can get one slideshow to work, but not four at the same time.  I would love some help getting all four to work.  Thanks!

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#slider1').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    autoControls: true,
    pause: 3000,
    slideMargin: 20
  });

  $('#slider2').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    autoControls: true,
    pause: 3000,
    slideMargin: 20
  });

  $('#slider3').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    autoControls: true,
    pause: 3000,
    slideMargin: 20
  });

  $('#slider4').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    autoControls: true,
    pause: 3000,
    slideMargin: 20
  });
  </script>
```

CSS:

```
.slider {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 400px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    height: 350px;
}

.slider img {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 350px;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 8;
}
```

Mark-up:

```
<div>
    <div class="slider">
        <ul id="slider1">
            <li><img src="images/.../art-1.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../art-2.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../art-3.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../art-4.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../art-5.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="slider">
        <ul id="slider2">
            <li><img src="images/.../bnl-1.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../bnl-2.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../bnl-3.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../bnl-4.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../bnl-5.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
     <div class="slider">
        <ul id="slider3">
            <li><img src="images/.../bge-1.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../bge-2.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../bge-3.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../bge-4.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../bge-5.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
     <div class="slider">
        <ul id="slider4">
            <li><img src="images/.../rtb-1.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../rtb-2.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../rtb-3.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../rtb-4.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../rtb-5.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with a simple slideshow is that it's, well, simple. Consider switching to [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/) or [Bootstrap's slider](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel), both of which accommodate multiple instances out of the box.

If you really want to fight with this one, pass the slideSwitch() function an ID and use that instead of '#slideshow'.

```
function slideSwitch(id, switchSpeed, activeClass) {
    var $active = $(id + ' IMG.' + activeClass);

    ...
```

You could also {gag} copy the function 3 times and change the ID in each of those, effectively running the script four times.

```
function slideSwitch1(switchSpeed,activeClass) {
    var $active = $('#slideshow1 IMG.' + activeClass);

function slideSwitch2(switchSpeed,activeClass) {
    var $active = $('#slideshow2 IMG.' + activeClass);

...
```

Comment: thank you.  Like I said, I'm not the best with javascript - I'm now trying to implement bxslider, as you suggested, and I'm still stuck.  JS conflict, perhaps?  But it's the only piece of JS that I'm running on the page.  Any further help would be appreciated...

Comment: Start a new question and we'll help you out. Hard to do so without some details. :-)

Comment: Done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407250/multiple-bxslider-instances-on-one-page.  Thanks @isherwood