# multiple bxSlider instances on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, bxslider

I have four slideshows on one page that I want to just run in loops, using [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/examples/multiple-slideshows)

I'm great with mark-up and CSS, but not yet very proficient with javascript.  I think I must be missing a key element, because none of the slideshows are currently working.  I would love some help getting all four to work.  Thanks!

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#slider1').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    autoControls: true,
    pause: 3000,
    slideMargin: 20
  });

  $('#slider2').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    autoControls: true,
    pause: 3000,
    slideMargin: 20
  });

  $('#slider3').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    autoControls: true,
    pause: 3000,
    slideMargin: 20
  });

  $('#slider4').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    autoControls: true,
    pause: 3000,
    slideMargin: 20
  });
  </script>
```

CSS:

```
.slider {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 400px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    height: 350px;
}

.slider img {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 350px;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 8;
}
```

Mark-up:

```
<div>
    <div class="slider">
        <ul id="slider1">
            <li><img src="images/.../art-1.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../art-2.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../art-3.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../art-4.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../art-5.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="slider">
        <ul id="slider2">
            <li><img src="images/.../bnl-1.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../bnl-2.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../bnl-3.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../bnl-4.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../bnl-5.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
     <div class="slider">
        <ul id="slider3">
            <li><img src="images/.../bge-1.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../bge-2.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../bge-3.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../bge-4.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../bge-5.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
     <div class="slider">
        <ul id="slider4">
            <li><img src="images/.../rtb-1.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../rtb-2.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../rtb-3.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../rtb-4.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/.../rtb-5.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This all looks correct. Something must be awry with your JS includes. jQuery first, then bxSlider? Paths correct?

Comment: Yes, I have jquery 1.8.3 called before bxSlider.  The only other js I have running, aside from analytics, is impress.js - maybe it's a conflict?

Comment: Unlikely, but possible. Disable impress.js and test. You should see errors in the console if there's a conflict.

Comment: @isherwood Got it working. I had the js in the head, and I moved it to the bottom of the page.  Thanks for your help, yesterday and today!  Really appreciated it.

Comment: Ah, yes. I should've seen that. You could also wrap your functions in $(document).ready(function() {} );

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just add a class to each of the <ul> elements and use that to target the bxSlider? Then you would only need one call instead of 4. I know it is faster by ID, but with only 4 sliders, there is really no performance issue.